# Browser turn into quicknotepad and bookmark

Tags: javascript, html, browser, bookmarks

I was random search on google "how can i use browser window as a notepad" , I found solution  Just type it on browser

`data:text/html, <html contenteditable>`

[Reference url](http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Use-your-browser-as-Notepad.html)

**My Question is**
Is there a option to save it on browser with typed data or  bookmark it with typed data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could do that but you need this html instead of `data:text/html, <html contenteditable>`

```
data:text/html, <html><body><input type=button id="add"
onclick='location.href=location.href.replace(/ENTER TEXT HERE/g,"")+
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML' 
value="ADD to URL" /><br/><br/><div contenteditable>ENTER TEXT HERE
```

This script adds your text body into URL then you are good to bookmark the current page in your browser. by pressing <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Can we go like this , we can avoid lengthy url http://jsfiddle.net/u0x8qzzk/ @venkat7668

Answer (score 1):

As [the page](http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Use-your-browser-as-Notepad.html) says

> If you want to save your content, do the usual browser save(CMD+S for OSX). It will save your content as html file.

If your not on mac then you can usually save the page by using `CTRL+S`. To resume editing just open the html file that was saved.